# using "in" operator to find element in pd.Series is not correct?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code

```py
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
sa = pd.Series(a)
"a" in sa
>> False
"a" in sa.values
>> True
"a" in list(sa)
>> True
```

Why "a" in sa return the False answer?

Comment: Note that `some_value in some_series` checks if `some_value` is in the **index** of `some_series`... so the above `0 in sa`, `1 in sa`, `2 in sa` will be `True`... and so will anything else that's in `sa.index`...

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is:

```py
sa.isin(['a'])
```

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) has also explained it with an example.

Comment: I need a boolean value with tiny code, this is not be best way to realize it. And also I'd like to know why ‘“a" in sa’ not works.

Comment: @pipdax because isin has a signature `isin(self,values)` made to compare multiple values so expects a list